# How to properly send input arrays in request?

Tags: php, html, arrays, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm working on the maintenance of a webpage made in Laravel using Blade Template. I need to send to the back end the form with a array pattern.

The page is for create a relation between teachers, subjects and the classes they teach the selected subject. 
There is a list with all the teachers and the user should select a subject and link to the according classes. A teacher can have more than 1 subject.

Here is the blade:

```
 @forelse ($teachers as $teacher)
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="small-12 large-12 column">
                                    <h2>Professor</h2>
                                    <p>{{ $teacher->name }}</p>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="professorId[{{ $teacher->id }}]"
                                        value="{{ $teacher->id }}" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="materiaTemplate{{ $teacher->id }}" class="row">                                
                                <div class="small-12 large-6 column">
                                    <h2>Matérias</h2>
                                    <select name="professorId[{{ $teacher->id }}][materias][]" required>
                                        <option value=""></option>
                                        @foreach ($subjects as $subject)
                                        <option value="{{ $subject->id }}">{{ $subject->name }}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="small-12 large-6 column">
                                    <h2>Turmas</h2>                               
                                    @forelse ($classes as $class)
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="{{ "turma".$class->id.'-'.$teacher->id }}"
                                        name="professorId[{{ $teacher->id }}][materias][][classes][]"
                                        value="{{ $class->id }}"><label
                                        for="{{ "turma".$class->id.'-'.$teacher->id }}">{{ $class->name }}</label>
                                    @empty
                                    <p>Nenhuma turma cadastrada.</p>
                                    @endforelse
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div id="addMateriaButton{{ $teacher->id}}" class="small-12 large-4 column">
                                    <label>
                                        &nbsp;
                                        <button type="button" class="button primary fullWidth"
                                            data-add-element="materiaTemplate{{ $teacher->id }}"
                                            data-insert-before="addMateriaButton{{ $teacher->id }}">
                                            <img src="<?= asset('img/site') ?>/icons/svg/plus.svg" alt="Icon plus"
                                                class="buttonIcon buttonIconLeft">
                                            Matéria
                                        </button>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            @empty
                            <div class="small-12 large-12 column">
                                <h2>Nenhum professor cadastrado.</h2>
                            </div>
                            @endforelse
```

Im trying to have something like this:

```
[professorIds] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [subjects] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [classes] => Array
                                (                                    
                                    [0] => 1

                                )
                        )
                )

        )
```

Need a little help with this.

Comment: Your hidden input is setting `professorId[{{ $teacher->id }}]` to an integer, but then you try to use `professorId[{{ $teacher->id }}]` as an array in later inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can post multi dimensional arrays as such:

> arrayName[FIRST_LAYER][SECOND_LAYER]...

```
<input name="teacher["Chemistry"]["John Well"]">
```